# prevent client side redirection in XSS

Tags: javascript, xss

Let's assume my website page html is:

```
<script>location.href = "/";</script>

Hello, {UNFILTERED USER INPUT HERE!}
```

When I try to inject JS code to it, I can't get it to execute because of the redirection.

I tried `loation.href = "MY_SITE";` and `Object.freeze(location);` but no luck.

Is there any way I can XSS it before the redirection?

or it's not vulnerable?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you want page.html to redirect, I suggest you use a server side approach.

Comment: @user2182349 I'm trying to inject JS to it as an attacker. (XSS) An attacker does not have access to the server side.

Comment: Read this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Types_of_Cross-Site_Scripting

Comment: @Gaurav I can't find a solution to my problem in this article

Comment: I'm pretty sure inline scripts are executed synchronously as soon as they're parsed, so the redirection always happens first.